# Creating an empty vector and read the file char by char. (C++)

Tags: c++

I need to create an empty vector that then opens and reads a file character by character and when it sees a digit, it puts the character back in the stream and reads the amount of money for the corresponding company as a number. I then need to construct a Company object using the name and money amount.

What I have so far....

```
int main(){

//Function
string readCompanyInfo(double money);

//Handles the file
ofstream company("companymoney.txt");

    std::vector<int> v;
    int sum (0);

    for (int i=1;i<=10;i++) v.push_back(i);

    while (!v.empty())          {sum += v.back(); v.pop_back();}


    std::cout << sum << '\n';

    return 0;
```

Thats the function, opening of the file, and an empty file. How would I go about reading the file and getting back the results I am looking for in the directions? 
Thanks for any help, I'm new at the obviously and if I can just see something correct, I have something to work off of in the future, thanks guys.

Comment: Use `std::getline` to read a line of text into a `std::string`.  Use `std::istringstream` with the string, to parse or extract the number.

Answer (score 1):

There are much more elegant and efficient methods than reading one character into a buffer.  The general rule of thumb is to read a line of text into a string and use `std::istringstream` to parse the string.  Reading of files is most efficient in block mode.

### Character by Character

If you must operate character by character and store into a `vector`, allocate a big vector before reading.  This will reduce the chances of `std::vector` resizing, which means allocating a bigger chunk of memory and copying the original values into the new vector area.

Read as much data into the vector with the fewest instructions.  Read up on the `back_inserter` and `std::vector`.

Next, using one pointer or index, to search the vector for your numerical digit.
Copy the pointer / index.
If possible, decrement the pointer / index, and verify that it is pointing to the dollar sign.

One of the pointers / indices is a "look ahead".

### Block Processing

The most efficient method is to work with groups or blocks of data.  Read blocks, search blocks.

You didn't state how your data is organized in the input file.

If the data is separated by tabs or commas, search the web and StackOverflow for "c++ read file comma separated" or "c++ read file tab separated".

I'll assume you are processing a text file.
Most text files have one record per line.
In this case, read a block of text (a line), into a `std::string` variable.
You can then search the variable for the '$' and use `std::istringstream` to convert the value from textual representation to numeric (`double`).

**Edit 1:**

### Regular Expressions

If you are good with regular expressions, you may be able to search the string or the vector of characters using a regular expression.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.. The text file contains the 1 company and their account balance on each line.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste some text of the input file, not as a picture, but copy from a text editor.